# Getting variables sent from url into wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, protocols

can somebody help me to know how to do it?
I want to know how to get the variables sent from url custom protocol into WPF, not command line as all tutorials on Internet show.
There are how to get it into command line:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

But how to get the args in wpf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the command-line arguments, and you don't want to create your own `Main()` (WPF generates one for you), you can use [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

Unlike with `Main()` `args`, the array returned from `GetCommandLineArgs()` contains the executable file name as its first item.